# Globally disable tooltip from C++ application

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, tooltip

By default if I set the tooltip on the control(s) the tooltips will be displayed when the mouse will be hovered.

However, what should I do if I want to disable the tooltips temporarily? All of them for all controls?

Is there some kind of message which will be sent in this case? Or I should simply jave some kind of variable which will be checked for displaying the tooltips?

Comment: There is no function SetTooltip() in Windows API.

Comment: My fault on that. I guessed winapi when it was tagged for windows.

Comment: :-D that's a first @drescherjm

Comment: Perhaps in [forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip.settooltip?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: I guess I worded the question incorrectly. Let me try and fix it. Soorry.

Comment: @drescherjm, WinAPI

Comment: Globally meaning all applications or all tooltips in a single application? And if the latter, are you the author of said application?

Comment: First of all we'd need to know what gui framework you wrote the program in

Comment: In C++/Win32, you use _TTM_ACTIVATE_ to activate/deactivate Tooltips (_ToolTip.Active_ property in .NET)

Comment: @Castorix, yes, but there 2 questions - first will it turn the tooltips for the application globally? and second - if I create a control with tooltip activated, what will happen?

Comment: You have to send this message to each tooltip window. To find tooltip windows of your application, call `EnumThreadWindows()`, for each window call `GetClassName()`, compare with `TOOLTIPS_CLASS`.

Comment: @Igor You can test by creating a Tooltip and adding several controls with TTM_ADDTOOL : TTM_ACTIVATE with FALSE will disable the Tooltips for all the controls...